# myClass not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, qt, scope

I make a project of music player in Qt based on QWidget class
and using widget.ui form.

I want to check that user will not add two labels with the same text, so I'm trying to add field: QList labelsList; 
in my widget.h file.
(every time user add label, than: labelsList.append(label), and before he can add this label program would iterate through labelsList and check if in list exists label with patricular text).

Although "myqlabel.h" is included, compiler says that 'myQLabel' was not declared in this scope... I don't know why. Kind of weird for me, but maybe I lack/forget some basic knowledge... ;/

Thanks for help!

Code (just needed fragments) below:

widget.h file:

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include "myqlabel.h"

#include <QList>
#include <QFormLayout>

#include <QSqlDatabase>
#include <QtSql>

#include <QMediaPlayer>


namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();


    // to check if label with input text already exists:

    // HERE OUR BAD FIELD:

    QList<myQLabel*> labelsList;



private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
    QMediaPlayer player;

    qint64 duration;

};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

myqlabel.h file:

```
#ifndef MYQLABEL_H
#define MYQLABEL_H

#include <QLabel>
#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"

#include <QFormLayout>
#include <QMouseEvent>

class myQLabel : public QLabel {

    Q_OBJECT
public:

    myQLabel(QString& text, QFormLayout* parent = 0) : QLabel(text){
        setAcceptDrops(true);
        position = amount;
        this->parent = parent;

        labelsList.append(this);
    }



};


#endif // MYQLABEL_H
```

Comment: A note about coding style: in Qt code it is customary to start class names with capital, so you should consider using `MyQLabel` as the class name here.

Comment: Oh, thanks :) My bad... I tried to distinguish it from built-in classes but we should stick to rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a circular dependency in your includes. This means that one of the headers is not seen depending on the order in which they are first included (due to the include guards).

Remove `#include "myqlabel.h"` from widget.h and add it to widget.cpp. Then forward declare `myQLabel` by adding

```
class myQLabel;
```

to widget.h.

Comment: Thanks, Man... kind of basic question it was, but You helped me very much ;( I have to put more attention on includes...